# IF statement as assignment expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The JSLint Error Explanations document (https://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-assignment-expression) says that if we evaluate an assignment expression (x = 0) the IF body will never be executed (y = 1).

```
var x, y;
if (x = 0) {
    y = 1;
}
```

> "The body of the if statement will not be executed because the
>   assignment expression results in undefined which is falsy."

But I could prove the opposite in `if (x = 1) { y = 1; }`. Is it a matter of JS version?

---

**UPDATE**

In fact I made a mistake assuming that is possible to use the result of an assignment as a test value. What I really could prove in the console was the assignment returning  a value, as in x = 1 outputting  1.

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. This assignment expression does not result in undefined. Consider leaving a comment on that page. ))

Comment: LOL, we both commented on the article. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That article excerpt is both correct **and** incorrect. It's correct that the body of the `if` will not be entered with `if (x = 0)`, but it's incorrect when it says why.

The incorrect part is highlighted:

> Instead of checking whether the variable `x` has the value `0` the example above will assign the value `0` to `x`. The body of the if statement will not be executed **because the assignment expression results in `undefined`** which is falsy *(sic)*.

That's just plain wrong. The result of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned, not `undefined`, so `if (x = 0)` won't enter the body of the `if` (because `0` is falsey), but `if (x = 1)` will (because `1` is truthy).

> Is it a matter of JS version?

No, it's always been this way. Someone just got it wrong in those docs.

> In fact I made a mistake assuming that is possible to use the result of an assignment as a test value.

It wasn't a mistake, you can — and sometimes, you want to. This is fairly common, for instance:

```
while ((thing = getMeTheNextThing()) != null) {
    // ...do something with `thing`
}
```

That's also using the result of an assignment as a test. Sometimes people even write it like this:

```
while (thing = getMeTheNextThing()) {
    // ...do something with `thing`
}
```

...although I never do, because it's just too easy to see that as an `==` and mess something up.

---

Note that it's very, very rare to want to *assign* to a variable within an `if` statement. It does happen, but it's really rare, and most style guides will suggest you break up the assignment and the branch.

Almost always, when you see `if (x = 0)`, what the author meant to write was `if (x == 0)` or `if (x === 0)`. That is, they meant to *test* the value of `x`, not assign a new value to `x`.

Example of what the JSLint docs mean about assigning zero:

```js
var x;

snippet.log("first test: using 0");
if (x = 0) {
  snippet.log("entered if body");
} else {
  snippet.log("entered else body");
}

snippet.log("second test: using 1");
if (x = 1) {
  snippet.log("entered if body");
} else {
  snippet.log("entered else body");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Crowder, you got the point and your answer was very clarifying! Thanks!